# Visual C++ 2010 Express Compile Error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I am experimenting with C++ but am having trouble compiling with Visual C++ 2010 Express through the command line.  I have been doing this without problem for several days, but now when typing `cl /EHsc program.cpp` into the Visual Studio Prompt, the program is not compiled.  It instead outputs the following:

```
/EHsc
program.cpp
0
```

I used the following page as my primary reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

Any help would be great since I have had no luck on google.  Thanks a lot, and please excuse the simple question.

Comment: What do you get in response to just `cl`?

Comment: Typing in just `cl` informs me that 'cl.exe' has stopped working.  The console itself doesn't crash, though.  Have also tried `cl /sc program.cpp` and the output is the same as in my original question.

By the way, running Vista Pro 64bit, SP2.

Comment: I think you need to uninstall and reinstall Visual C++ Express then.  If it's crashing when not even fed any source code to process, one of the core files must be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that shortly and post the results!

Comment: I wish you luck.  The Visual Studio install takes quite a while, and then you'll need to reinstall SP1 afterwards.  You could try a "repair install", but I think a total uninstall/reinstall is more likely to work.

Comment: I tried the reinstall with no luck, but then saw the below comment.  Nonetheless, thanks very much for the reply yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a guess at what is in program.cpp.  I bet it is a small program that prints the values of argv[i] in a for() loop.  If that's anywhere accurate, you probably got yourself into trouble earlier with a wrong command line and accidentally created cl.exe instead of program.exe.

Well, it works.  Type "del cl.exe" to get rid of it.

Do consider using the "visual" part of Visual Studio.  The IDE has *lots* of ways to help you fall into the pit of success.  Start that with File + New Project.

Comment: You're spot on!  I don't quite understand what I may have done incorrectly, but using del fixed my problem immediately.  Thanks ever so much!

Comment: Wow, pumps fist for psychic debugging overkill achievement.  Did I guess the source code correctly?  I was unsure about the last 0.